May and how I rewrite X-Forwarded-Proto header for ingress in ingress-nginx configuration in Kubernetes/AWS NLB?
I have:

EKS cluster (AWS)
ingress-nginx deployed as LoadBalancer (corresponding nlb active in EC2 configuration)
NLB terminates https with ACM certificate
Application in some namespace which listen on port 3000
Application requires header X-Forwarded-Proto set as http or https - exactly as user entered in browser (behavior depends on link + proto)

Now I can have http in X-Forwarded-Proto only - I can't set X-Forwarded-Proto depending on user request (NLB terminates https and my ingress-nginx has http only) even I can't change http to https - when I use snippet (configuration-snippet) it adds a line to nginx.conf file but doesn't changes the existing one (set X-Forwarded-Proto $pass-access-scheme).
Maybe somebody can help with this issue?
I tried:
configuration-snippet and server-snippet parameters in the ingress config in annotations - it adds lines to nginx.conf, but doesn't change ingress behavior.
